# LinkedIn Javascript SDK API "uh oh" Error Popup

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I continually get the "uh oh" error from the linkedin login popup. 
[image]

I've gone over the documentation and setup not to mention the forums. In my settings for my LinkedIn App these are the settings I've added in.

**AuthPage Settings**

[image]

**Settings Page**

[image]

**Javascript Settings**

[image]

Could this be because I'm using a localhost domain? I've seen other people use it however perhaps they are using it in a different way.

**My Code (React/JS)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './login.scss';
import config from './config';

class Landing extends Component {
    // Creates the <script> tag 
    componentDidMount() {
        const e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.async = false;
        e.src = 'http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js';
        const t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t);
    }

    //Trigger Login for LinkedIn
    linkedinLogin = () => {
        window.IN.init({
            api_key: config.linkedin
        });
        setTimeout(this.getUserDetails, 1000);
    }

    // Gets the User Information 
    getUserDetails = () => {
        console.log('GetUserDetails');
        window.IN.User.authorize(() => {
            console.log('Authorizing')

            window.IN.API.Profile('me')
                .fields(['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'pictureUrl', 'publicProfileUrl'])
                .result(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    alert(`Successfull login from linkedin : ${result.values[0].firstName} ${result.values[0].lastName}`);
                })
                .error(err => console.log('Import error - Error occured while importing data'));

            window.IN.User.isAuthorized(result => console.log(result));
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='logo'><span>Face</span>timonial</div>
                <div className='title-wrapper'>
                    <h1 className='header'>Best way to get a <br /> recommendation!</h1>
                    <h2 className='sub-header'>
                        Facetimonial is a video base recommendation platform and it will
                        express why you are the best fit for the next job you apply!
                    </h2>
                </div>

                <button className='login-btn' onClick={() => this.linkedinLogin()}>
                    <p>Login With LinkedIn</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Landing;
```

So to sum up the code when the view initialized I'm creating the  tag that linkedin requires. When the user clicks the button it fires the linkedinLogin function which then fires the getUserDetails function. However this is the where the problems arise. I get the functions from the linkedIn src tag. However it wont authorize the user. The error doesn't help either...